# How do I update UI while calling a long running process in AJAX/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have mutiple processes that need to be called in series (I am using synchronous AJAX calls).  I would like to display status of a long running process after its completion and then proceed to the next one.  Here is a sample code I have written.

```
    var counter = 0;
function runProcess(input, output) {
    doWork();
    doWork();
    doWork();
};
function doWork() {
    counter++;
    document.getElementById('<%=this.progressMonitor.ClientID%>').innerHTML += "Running " + counter;

    // some lengthy calculations
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        var foo = Math.random();
    }
    setTimeout(updateStatus, 1000);
};
function updateStatus() {
    document.getElementById('<%=this.progressMonitor.ClientID%>').innerHTML += "Done " + counter;
}
```

When I run this, I get the following response:

Running 1Running 2Running 3Done 3Done 3Done 3

I would like to get

Running 1Done 1Running 2Done 2Running 3Done 3

If I insert a alert() statement in updateStatus function, then I get the response/execution order I want.  Is the browser creating 3 threads for 3 function calls and executing them asynchronously?

How can I run this in series? Is setTimeout implemented correctly?  Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: How do the Ajax calls figure in here?  Do they go where you have the Math loop in your sample?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just noticed your your prior post. To clarify, this was a sample code. In the real world, doWork will be replaced by a CallService function which will call a WCF service synchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to queue up AJAX calls.  jQuery provides a good queue function, so you can make sure a series of functions gets called one after the other.  Mootools and other frameworks provide similar functionality.

Here is the code from my **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slashingweapon/eaa6Q/)** that shows how to do it.

```
var queueElement = $("#output");
var counter = 0;

function doWork(next) {
    queueElement.append("Starting " + counter + "<br/>");
    counter++;
    $.ajax('/echo/json/').always(function() {
        queueElement.append("Ending " + counter + "<br/>");
        next();
    });
}

queueElement.queue('workQueue', doWork);
queueElement.queue('workQueue', doWork);
queueElement.queue('workQueue', doWork);
queueElement.dequeue('workQueue'); // start the work queue
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you have to understand about Javascript in the browser is that it is single-threaded.  When you change the DOM the screen does not change until your script relinquishes control.

Here is the real sequence of events when you call doWork() twice:

1. call `doWork()`
2. `doWork()` adds running message
3. queue up a call to `updateStatus()` to execute later
4. call `doWork()` again
5. `doWork()` adds running message
6. queue up a call to `updateStatus()` to execute later
7. `runProcess()` exits and returns control back to the browser
8. The browser updates the screen with the running messages
9. The first `updateStatus()` call is made.  After it is finished, the screen is updated
10. The second `updateStatus()` call is made.  After it is finished, the screen is updated

You can get what you want by not messing with the `updateStatus()` call at all, and just print out your done messages from inside `doWork()`.

Comment: Thank you.  It makes me feel better that given your explanation that it's still single threaded.  The issue I have is that browser executes everything and then sends the response (everything together). I would like to notify the user as soon as each service is completed. I thought setTimeout will give the browser enough time to display the message but it does not seem to work. I have tried many code samples but have not been able to figure this out.  I am using IE9 with windows 7.  Thanks again.

Comment: There's a way to queue the ajax calls so they execute one after the other.  I'll work up a sample and post it in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Queue works great.  Using queue on $.ajax methods that need to be called in series works great.  If I used the "async: false" option without using a queue, UI only gets refreshed after all of long running processes are complete.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  Here is my final code in case anyone is looking:

```
function callService(url, workflowid, modelid, next) {
        var jData = {};
        jData.workflowid = workflowid;
        jData.modelid = modelid;
        //alert(JSON.stringify(jData));
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(jData),
            success: function (oResult) {
                $("#Message").append("&nbsp;&nbsp;" + oResult.Message);
                if (!oResult.Success) {
                    $("#<%:this.FailureText.ClientID %>").append("&nbsp;&nbsp;" + oResult.Error);
                } else { next(); }
            },
            error: function (exc) {
                $("#Message").append("&nbsp;&nbsp;" + exc.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
    function runServices() {
        var queueElement = $("#q");
        var queueStatus = $("#Message");

        queueStatus.append("<br/>Starting workflows at : " + new Date() + "<br/>");
        var list = $(":input:checkbox:checked"); // getting all selected checkboxes.
        $(list.each(function () {
            var workflowid = $(this).val();
            queueElement.queue("WorkflowQ", function (next) {
                callService("/Services/Workflow.svc/rest/runworkflow", workflowid, document.getElementById('<%=this.MODELID.ClientID%>').value, next);
            });
        }));          
        queueElement.dequeue("WorkflowQ");
    };

    <input type="button" id="ExecuteButton" value="Execute Workflow" class="button" onclick="runServices();"/>

<div id="Message"></div>
<div id="q"></div>
```